# How to publish a page to two sites?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I have a root site and a sub-site. I want to enable the following function -- when the sub-site administrator publishing a page, the administrator could select to publish to the sub-site only or publish to both root site and sub-site.

Any ideas how to implement this? I am not sure whether there is any ready-to-use solution without writing code?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about something along the lines of what SharePoint Content Deployment offers?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263428.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/10/30/content-deployment-the-complete-guide-part-1-the-basics.aspx